# Apply filter to search in django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to search a user name in the database and list all the results of the search in another page.
In this page, on the listed results, I want to apply some filtering.
It sounds like a simple thing to do but I am having difficulties.
I am using django-filters.

in the **home.html** I have my search

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = {% url 'users:index' %} method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search"
                       placeholder="Search a user...">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="action">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The results are listed in **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Users App</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="GET">
    {{ filter.form }}
    <button type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>
{% if filter.qs %}
    <ul>
    {% for user in filter.qs %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'users:detail' user.id %}">{{ user.name }}, {{ user.nationality }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No users available.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

now if I try to apply the filter off filter.form I get the error Cannot use None as a query value.
Here are the **views.py**:

```
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'users/home.html')

class UserListView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/index.html'
    # queryset = User.objects.filter(name__icontains='Bruno') same as
    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        return User.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = UserFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:user_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters as filters
from .models import User
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'surname',)
```

the problem is that after the search as been sent with a POST method, if I try to use again the UserListView view  the command `self.request.GET.get('search')` returns an empty object.

How can I filter on the results of the search? Is there a way to save the search query such that the filter is applied only on the searched items?

Answer (score 0):

For the "Cannot use None as a query value" error you can update your `get_queryset()` to check for None or empty values.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('search')
    if query:
        return User.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    else:
        return User.objects.none()  # or .all() depending on what you want to show
```

Comment: Thanks Ben but his will not solve my problem, I need to somehow keep the 'search' query such that the filtering is done on the results of the search, and not on the complete database

Answer (score 0):

If your results view also has the same filtering fields, then you can just pass again the previously used parameters to that view.

Something like this:

**views.py**

```py
def results_view(request):
    results = []
    # Your search/filtering code here...
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    return render(request, 'results.html', {
        'results': results,
        'query': query
    })
```

**results.html**

```html
<form>
    <input name="query" value="{% if query %}{{ query }}{% endif %}" />
</form>
```